# Como resolver Fat Jar Export: Could not find class-path entry

Tags: java, classes, build, library

Estou tendo sérios problemas na exportação de um programa feito no Eclipse e estou começando a me odiar por tentar ser organizado.

Importei para o meu projeto duas bibliotecas de terceiros (JavaMail e iText 5). Os JARs delas eu baixei da Internet e deixei salvo na minha pasta Downloads. Importei os JARs (no caso External JARs) pelo `Build Path...` e tudo estava funcionando. O programa estava rodando perfeitamente e eu estava tendo êxito em todas as exportações.

Mas aí eu fui tentar ser organizado... Movi o JAR do JavaMail (que não tinha pasta) e a pasta do iText - tudo - para dentro da pasta do meu Project. Não coloquei nem dentro da pasta /src nem da /bin, apenas dentro da pasta do Project. Para ficar ainda mais organizado, criei uma pasta /lib dentro da pasta do meu Project e coloquei essas bibliotecas lá.

Ou seja:

```
- PASTA DO PROJETO
--- src
--- bin
--- lib
------ JavaMail.jar
------ Pasta do iText com os seus respectivos JARs
```

Entendo que mexer no destino desses arquivos, depois de importados, pode causar sérios problemas. Então não pensei duas vezes: fui no `Build Path...`, excluí as bibliotecas (importadas da antiga pasta Downloads), e as re-importei da nova pasta /lib.

Aparentemente tudo certo... O programa roda perfeitamente. Tudo funciona como antes. Inclusive os methods relativos às bibliotecas JavaMail e iText.

Só que...

Quando eu exporto o programa (pelo `Runnable JAR file`), o seguinte erro aparece para TODOS os External JARs:

**Fat Jar Export: Could not find class-path entry for [caminho da biblioteca]**

Isso não impede a exportação. Ela acontece normalmente. Mas quando eu abro o JAR gerado, ele apresenta um erro e fecha.

O que está faltando aqui?

Comment: `[caminho da biblioteca]` que aparece no erro é o caminho atual ou o antigo?

Comment: @jbueno É o caminho atual...